# Author-recommendation for styles similar to Lovecraft?

Tags: style, vocabulary

I enjoy the verbose and elevated use of words Lovecraft is inclined to employ. I'm hoping to read other authors who have a similar style, especially when such a technique is used to create strong visual or emotional impact.

Is there any recommendations?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Writers. Unfortunately, this is more of a question for readers. You might try over on Literature SE, though I am not sure if they accept requests for author recommendations either.

Comment: Unfortunately recommendations are off-topic on Literature as well. I think this is more of a chatroom/forum question than something that will work here. Placing this on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Some of HPL's influences are Robert W. Chambers, Arthur Machen, and Lord Dunsany. That should get you started.